# Unable to tag AppConfig configuration resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-app-config

According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS AppConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsappconfig.html), the *configuration* resource type has ARN format `arn:${Partition}:appconfig:${Region}:${Account}:application/${ApplicationId}/environment/${EnvironmentId}/configuration/${ConfigurationProfileId}` and supports the global `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}` condition key.

However, the AppConfig API actions pertaining to resource tags ([`ListTagsForResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_ListTagsForResource.html), [`TagResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_TagResource.html), [`UntagResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_UntagResource.html)) return `BadRequestException` when provided a configuration resource ARN:

```
$ aws aws appconfig list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:appconfig:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:application/XXXXXXX/environment/XXXXXXX/configuration/XXXXXXX
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the TagResource operation: arn:aws:appconfig:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:application/XXXXXXX/environment/XXXXXXX/configuration/XXXXXXX contains an unsupported resource type.[application, XXXXXXX, environment, XXXXXXX, configuration]
```

(The same error also occurs when attempting the operation via the AWS SDK, so it's not limited to the AWS CLI.)

The configuration resource ARN above is valid, since its use in the following IAM policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
      "appconfig:GetLatestConfiguration",
      "appconfig:StartConfigurationSession"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:appconfig:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:application/XXXXXXX/environment/XXXXXXX/configuration/XXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

makes [`StartConfigurationSession`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_appconfigdata_StartConfigurationSession.html) return the expected `AccessDeniedException` ending in "explicit deny in an identity-based policy".

Furthermore, [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS AppConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsappconfig.html) shows that `TagResource` and `UntagResource` *do* accept configuration resource types.

If it's not possible to tag an AppConfig configuration resource, then it's not possible to control access to the `GetLatestConfiguration` and `StartConfigurationSession` operations using tags:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "appconfig:GetLatestConfiguration",
      "appconfig:StartConfigurationSession"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:appconfig:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:application/XXXXXXX/*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "aws:ResourceTag/Tag": "Value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The observed behavior does not match the AWS documentation, and seems like an oversight in the AWS AppConfig API.